# Unable to boot with newer kernel: no working init found

Tags: boot, init

Ubuntu does not boot with  kernel 5.11.0-18-generic: if I just boot as usual, I get just a blank screen (with motherboard logo, if there was no grub menu), if I remove options `quite splash` or boot in recovery mode, I get `Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.` error ([boot log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEYnR.jpg)).

I can boot with older kernel: 5.11.0-17-generic (both in normal and recovery modes). Almost sure, that I could also boot with this kernel, and I don't know, what happened.
I have tried to update initrd and grub, but that didn't help:

```
update-initramfs -u -k 5.11.0-18-generic
update-grub
```

I have disk encryption installed, this happens before password prompt.